# How to write command line argument dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am writing a command line program in NodeJS, where my current thinking is that I would like to have the argument parsing and logic in `index.js` and then have the actual code in functions in separate files.

The problem I have run into is how to write the argument dependencies and conflicts. For some reason `cmd` never contains the arguments. It only works with `--help`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I inside the switch check for existence or non-existence of other arguments?

```
'use strict'
const minimist = require('minimist')

module.exports = () => {
  const args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2))

  let cmd = args._[0] || 'help'

  if (args.version || args.v) {
    console.log("Version 0.1")
    exit
  }

  if (args.help || args.h) {
    const help =
`
Usage: ddparser [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Parses DD toml files and updates a webpage accordingly.

  --help              Prints this help page
  --validate          Validates input file               [requires --input]
  --k1-dry-run        Print K1 changes without doing it  [requires --input] [conflicts with --k1-commit]
  --k1-commit         Commit k1 changes to website       [requires --k1-token] [conflicts with --k1-dry-run]
  --k1-token          K1 token                           [requires --k1-commit]
  --input             DD toml file to parse [required]

`
    console.log(help)
  }

  // all args below needs content from the toml file to work
  // should exit with error if config.toml isn't found

  switch (cmd) {
    case 'validate':
      // error if --input is not specified
      // error if any other argument is given
      // read config.toml
      // read --input toml file
      break

    case 'k1-dry-run':
      // error if --input is not specified
      // error if any other argument is given
      // run --validate first and error if it fails
      // read config.toml
      // read --input toml file
      break

    case 'k1-commit':
      // error if --input is not specified
      // error if --k1-token is not specified
      // run --validate first and error if it fails
      // read config.toml
      // read --input toml file
      break

    case 'k1-token':
      // error if --input is not specified
      // error if --k1-commit is not specified
      // this argument is just a dependency for other args
       break

    default:
      console.log('XXX is not a valid argument.')
      break
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`minimist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist):

> `argv._` contains all the arguments that didn't have an option
>   associated with them.
>
> Numeric-looking arguments will be returned as numbers unless
>   `opts.string` or `opts.boolean` is set for that argument name.
>
> Any arguments after `'--'` will not be parsed and will end up in `argv._`.

So instead of calling `cmd.js --validate`, call it as `cmd.js validate` otherwise you can do:

```
  let cmd = Object.keys(args).find(item => item !== '_') || 'help'
```

As a side note, you're doing: `exit` instead of  `process.exit()`, and you'll get:

```
ReferenceError: exit is not defined
```